# How to Animate UIView on a line path without using UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

I have draw UIView say rectangle(player) and line, using context using draw(_ rect: CGRect) method.

I want to move the player on a line when clicking the play button.

I have searched lots of, but I found only for UIBezierpath but I want to use it with context
and I have tried some code name with **playAnimation function**.

```
class CanvasView : UIView{


    //  straight line
    var lineStartPoint = CGPoint()
    var lineEndpoint = CGPoint()
    var lineStrokeList = [Lines]()
    var lineDict :  [String : Lines] = [:]
    var lineActionDictionary : [String : [String : Lines]] = [:]
    var linesPath : CGPath?

    //player
    var playerPoint : CGPoint?
    var playerList = [Players]()
    var playerDict : [Int : Players] = [:]
    var selectedPlayerNumber : Int = 0


    //action
    var actionDict : [String : String] = ["1" : "1"]
    var actionKeyIndex = String()
    var actionList : [String] = [String]()



    // common
    var strokeWidth : CGFloat = 2.0
    var currentColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    var imageSize : CGFloat = 30.0
    private var selectedShape : ShapeType = .player



    //MARK: Touches Began
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        switch selectedShape {
        case .player:
            playerPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            playerDict.forEach { (key,value) in
                if value.rect.contains(playerPoint ?? CGPoint()){
                    selectedPlayerNumber = Int(key)
                    self.playerDict.removeValue(forKey: selectedPlayerNumber)
                    return
                }
            }
            setNeedsDisplay()
        case .line:
            let pos = touch.location(in: self)
            lineStartPoint = pos
            lineEndpoint = pos
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    //MARK: Touches Moved
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let isfreeDrawSelected = isfreeDrawSelected

        switch selectedShape {
        case .player:
            playerPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            setNeedsDisplay()
        case .line:
            lineEndpoint = touch.location(in: self)
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }

    }

    //MARK: Touches Ended
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

        switch selectedShape {
        case .player:
            if playerPoint != nil {
                let point = CGPoint(x: playerPoint!.x, y: playerPoint!.y)

                let x = playerPoint!.x - 15
                let y = playerPoint!.y - 15
                let playerRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)

                let playerstruct = Players(point: point,rect: playerRect)
                playerList.append(playerstruct)
                playerDict[selectedPlayerNumber] = playerstruct
                playerPoint = nil
                selectedPlayerNumber += 1
                setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        case .line:
            lineEndpoint = touch.location(in: self)

            if !playerDict.isEmpty{
                if lineActionDictionary[actionKeyIndex]?[String(selectedPlayerNumber)] != nil{


                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "You can't add mutiple lines for action \(actionKeyIndex)", preferredStyle: .alert)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { alertAction in

                        debugPrint(self.lineActionDictionary)
                    }))
                    UIApplication.shared.windows
                        .last?.rootViewController?
                        .present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
                }
                else{

                    let line = Lines(startPoint: lineStartPoint, endPoint: lineEndpoint, color: currentColor, width: strokeWidth)
                    lineStrokeList.append(line)
                    lineDict[String(selectedPlayerNumber)] = line

                    if lineActionDictionary[actionKeyIndex] != nil {
                        lineActionDictionary[actionKeyIndex]!.updateValue(line, forKey: String(selectedPlayerNumber))

                    }else{
                        lineActionDictionary[actionKeyIndex] = lineDict

                    }

                }
                lineStartPoint = CGPoint()
                lineEndpoint = CGPoint()
                lineDict.removeAll()
                setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }
    }


    //MARK: Draw
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }


        if playerPoint != nil {
            let x = (playerPoint?.x)! - 15
            let y = (playerPoint?.y)! - 15
            let player = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)

            context.addRect(player)
            context.drawPath(using: .stroke)
            linesPath = context.path
        }

        if !playerDict.isEmpty{
            playerDict.forEach { (key,value) in

                let x = value.point.x - 15
                let y = value.point.y - 15
                let player = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                let colorView = UIView(frame: player)

                context.addRect(player)
                context.drawPath(using: .stroke)
            }
        }


        if lineStartPoint.x > 0 && lineEndpoint.y > 0{
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            context.setLineWidth(2.0)
            context.move(to: lineStartPoint)
            context.addLine(to: lineEndpoint)
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
            context.strokePath()
        }

        if !lineActionDictionary.isEmpty{

            lineActionDictionary.forEach { (actionkey,actionvalue) in

                actionvalue.forEach { (playerkey,playervalue) in

                    let startPoint = playervalue.startPoint
                    let endPoint = playervalue.endPoint
                    let color = playervalue.color
                    let width = playervalue.width
                    context.setLineCap(.round)
                    context.setLineWidth(width)
                    context.move(to: startPoint)
                    context.addLine(to: endPoint)
                    context.setStrokeColor(color)
                    context.strokePath()
                }
            }
        }


    }

    func selectedShape(selctedShapes : ShapeTypes) {
        selectedShape = selctedShapes
    }



    func playAnimation(){

        switch selectedShape {
        case .player:
            break
        case .line:
            let player = playerList.first
            let views = UIView(frame: player!.rect)

            views.alpha = 1.0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                views.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20)
            }, completion: {
                (value: Bool) in
                debugPrint(">>> Animation done.")
            })

        }

    }
}
```

#ShapeTypes Enum

```
enum ShapeTypes : Int {
    case player = 0
    case line

}
```

#UIViewController

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)

class TestVC : UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var colorPicker: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderMaxValueLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var radiusSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var tv: CanvasView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shapeSegment : UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var playerFormationPickerDoneBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerFormationPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerFormationTF: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var actionPickerDoneBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var actionPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var actionPickerTF: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var addActionBtn: UIBarButtonItem!


    //playerformation pickerview
    var playerFormationPickerData = String()
    var playerFormationPickerSelectedIndex = Int()
    var isPlayerFormationSelected : Bool = false
    var playerViewArray: [PlayerView] = []
    var pickerViewListData: [String] = [String]()


    //action pickerview
    var actionPickerData = String()
    var actionPickerSelectedIndex = Int()


    @IBAction func actionPickerDoneButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        actionPickerDoneBtn.isHidden = true
        actionPicker.isHidden = true
        actionPickerTF.text = actionPickerData
        tv.actionKeyIndex = actionPickerTF.text?.components(separatedBy: " ").last ?? ""
        debugPrint(tv.actionKeyIndex)
    }

    func setSliderThumb(_ color: UIColor, _ width : CGFloat) {
        let circleImage = makeCircleWith(size: CGSize(width: width, height: width),
                                         backgroundColor: color)
        radiusSlider.setThumbImage(circleImage, for: .normal)
        radiusSlider.setThumbImage(circleImage, for: .highlighted)
    }

    fileprivate func makeCircleWith(size: CGSize, backgroundColor: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setFillColor(backgroundColor.cgColor)
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        let bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        context?.addEllipse(in: bounds)
        context?.drawPath(using: .fill)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
    @IBAction func radiusSliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let radius = Int(radiusSlider.value)
        tv.radius = CGFloat(radius)
        sliderMaxValueLbl.text = String(radius)
    }

    @IBAction func playAnimationAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        tv.playAnimation()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        radiusSlider.minimumValue = 30
        radiusSlider.maximumValue = 100
        radiusSlider.value = 0
        sliderMaxValueLbl.text = String(Int(radiusSlider.value))
        setSliderThumb(UIColor.white, 20)

        if let img = UIImage(named: "ground") {             //background image
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tv.frame.size)
            img.draw(in: tv.bounds)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            if let image = image {
                tv.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
                tv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            }
        }

        actionPicker.delegate = self
        actionPicker.dataSource = self
        actionPicker.isHidden = true
        actionPickerTF.delegate = self

        actionPickerTF.textAlignment = .center
        actionPickerTF.placeholder = "Select action"

        actionPickerDoneBtn.isHidden = true
        actionPickerDoneBtn.tintColor = .systemBlue

        tv.actionKeyIndex = tv.actionDict["1"] ?? ""
        tv.actionList = ["action \(tv.actionKeyIndex)"]

        actionPickerData = tv.actionList[0]
        actionPickerTF.text = actionPickerData

        tv.currentColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }

    @IBAction func addActionButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let count = tv.actionList.count + 1
        let element = tv.lineActionDictionary.keys.max()
      //  let element = tv.actionDict.values.max() // find max dict value
        guard let maxValue = element?.first?.wholeNumberValue else { return }
          debugPrint(maxValue)

        tv.actionKeyIndex = String(maxValue + 1)
        actionPickerTF.text = "action \(tv.actionKeyIndex)"
        tv.actionList.append("action \(tv.actionKeyIndex)")
        actionPicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }

    @IBAction func selectShapeSegmentAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        let selectShape : ShapeType = ShapeTypes(rawValue: shapeSegment.selectedSegmentIndex) ?? .player
        tv.selectedShape(selctedShape: selectShape)
    }
}

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
extension TestVC : UIPickerViewDelegate {


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView == actionPicker{
            actionPickerData = tv.actionList[row]
            actionPickerTF.text = actionPickerData
            actionPickerSelectedIndex = actionPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
extension TestVC : UIPickerViewDataSource {


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return tv.actionList.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return tv.actionList[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        var title = UILabel()
        if let view = view {
            title = view as! UILabel
        }

        if pickerView == actionPicker {
            title.text =  tv.actionList[row]
        }


        title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
        title.textColor = UIColor.black
        title.textAlignment = .center
        return title

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Your approach of overriding `draw()` will make it rather difficult to animate that rectangle. I think you'd find it much easier - both overall and for animating - to use either sublayers or subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have some `customView` and you want to simply temporary move it a little bit down. Here is lightweight solution.

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

func animateGoingDown() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.customView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 200)
    }
}

func animateGoingToOriginalPosition() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.customView.transform = .identity
    }
}
```

Howefully this is what you are searching for. If you have some questions, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: hello,
i have write in playAnimation 
```
            playerList.forEach { player in
                let rect  = player.rect
                let playerview = UIView(frame: rect)

                CanvasView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.plainView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.lineEndpoint.y)
                }
            }
```
but it animate whole CanvasView not player(rectangle)

Comment: You neet to transform the same View that is added as subview of your ViewControllers view and not creating new view from some saved Player frame value

Comment: as you can see in my posted question,
i have created player structure.
and in my comment, 

`playerList.forEach { player in let rect = player.rect 
let playerview = UIView(frame: rect) CanvasView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { self.plainView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.lineEndpoint.y) } }`
i want to use playerview, how can i do that?
as you said, i have to transform my subview to viewcontroller,
my question is playerview isn't subview of vc?

i'm new to ios swift.